# What if $\operatorname{char}\mathbb{K}$ is not $0$ or if $\mathbb{K}$ is not algebraically closed? (Nullstellensatz)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Given a field $\mathbb{K}$ which is algebraically closed and of characteristic 0, we can say exactly what the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ are and they correspond to points in $\mathbb{K}^n$ (thanks to the Nullstellensatz).

Can I say anything about the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{K}$ if char$\mathbb{K}\neq0$ or if it is not algebraically closed?

Thanks.

Comment: The nullstellensatz does not require characteristic zero. Generalizations can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz .

Comment: Even Hilbert's Nullstellensatz says something far more interesting than "maximal ideals = points": it says a polynomial function $f$ vanishes on the zero locus of an ideal $I$ of $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ if and only if a power of $f$ is contained in $I$. This really and honestly does require the field to be algebraically closed.

Answer (score 10):

1) Characteristic $0$ is irrelevant: if $K$ is an algebraically closed field  of *any*  characteristic the maximal ideals of $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ are the ideals $I_a=(x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$ consisting of the polynomials $f\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ vanishing on $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in K^n$.

2) For an arbitrary, not necessarily algebraically closed,  field $K$ the maximal ideals of  $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ correspond to the closed points of affine space $\mathbb A^n_K$.
A rough description of these points is as follows:
Choose an algebraic closure $K^a$ of $K$. There is a canonical morphism of schemes $\mathbb A^n_{K^a} \to \mathbb A^n_K$, dual to the inclusion  $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to K^a[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  The closed points of   $\mathbb A^n_K$ are the images of the  closed points of $\mathbb A^n_{K^a}$.
 Here are a few facts surrounding/interpreting  that geometric description :

a) A prime  ideal $\mathfrak p\subset K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$  is maximal $\iff $ the extension $K\subset Frac(A/\mathfrak p)$ is finite.
b) An ideal $I\subset K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$  is maximal $\iff $ there exists $a\in (K^a)^n$ such that $I$ is the zero set $$I_a= \lbrace f\in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\mid f(a)=0\rbrace $$   c) Given $a,b \in  (K^a)^n$ , the corresponding maximal ideals $I_a, I_b$ are equal $\iff$ there exists a $K$-automorphism $s\in Aut(K^a/K)$ such that $s(a_i)=b_i$. (Note that $K^a/K$ is not assumed Galois.)

Geometrically b)  says that $\mathbb A^n_{K^a} \to \mathbb A^n_K$ is surjective and c) describes the fibers of that morphism as the orbits of $Aut(K^a/K)$ acting on $(K^a)^n$

Comment: Thank you! So I guess I only need to know what happens if the field is both of positive characteristic and it is not algebraically closed!

Comment: Dear user, yes and no: if the field $K$ is non algebraically closed of characteristic zero and $n=1$, the determination of the maximal ideals of $K[x]$ amounts to  that of the irreducible monic polynomials in $K[x]$. Even if there are irreducibility algorithms and criteria , the problem remains non-trivial and is even more difficult  for $n\gt 1$.

Answer (score 8):

If the field has characteristic $0$ (or, more generally, is perfect) then you can use Galois theory: the maximal ideals correspond to orbits of points in $\overline{K}^n$ by ${\rm Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$. Given a point $P=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ in $\overline{K}^n$, evaluation of polynomials in $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ at $P$ is a $K$-alg. hom from polynomials to $\overline{K}$ whose kernel is a maximal ideal of $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. All maximal ideals arise in this way, and two points $P$ and $Q$ give rise to the same maximal ideal iff $Q = \sigma(P)$ for some $\sigma$ in ${\rm Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$.